# foreign key constraint on update cascade on delete cascade

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: one and two. I have a primary key (id) in table one.

Table One:

```
CREATE TABLE `one` (
`id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`first_name` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`last_name` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`salary` int(100) NOT NULL,
`login_date_time` datetime NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

id    first_name    last_name    salary  login_date_time
```

Table Two

```
CREATE TABLE two AS (SELECT id,salary ,CONCAT(first_name, ',', last_name) AS Name from one)
```

Now adding the foreign key to id as:

```
ALTER TABLE two
ADD CONSTRAINT `0_38775` FOREIGN KEY (id)
REFERENCES one(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

the table `two` comes as with the values from table `one`:

```
id    salary       name
```

Now to maintain referential integrity, how to update the values of `table two` when `table one` is updated. And also I cannot delete rows from `table one` and cannot insert rows to `table two`.

How can I update all the columns of `table two` when `table one` is updated/inserted. or insert explicitly into `table two`

Comment: What scripts are you running, and what errors are you getting?  For inserting, you should be able to insert into `one` first, and then `two`.  For deleting, if you delete a row from `one`, it will automatically delete any associated rows from `two`.

Comment: i dont have any values in table one but when i enter the value in table one its not inserted in table 2

Comment: A constraint doesn't automatically **insert** records; you would need a trigger for that.

Comment: so we can write an update trigger to do it  without mentioning the ON UPDATE and DELETE cascade or have to mention it to do the trigger work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for the case of `delete`, when you delete the row from table 1, all the rows corresponding to that id will be deleted from table 2.

In case of `update`, if you want first name and last name to be updated in table 2 when they are altered in table 1 then you will have to write an update `trigger` for that.

Comment: thanks! to do it work we can write an update trigger. but should we mention that ON UPDATE cascade when creating keys to make the trigger work or its not neccessary?

Comment: It is not necessary. Update trigger will take care of all the update operations.